# Driver file information for all network adapters [C#]

Tags: c#, nic

I am trying to get the driver file information for all network adapter on my machine.

DOES anyone know, how to achive using C#

[image]

Comment: First result from google: [How can I get a my servers Network Adapter(s) driver filename and version info using Powershell?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ben_parker/archive/2009/11/13/how-can-i-get-network-adapter-driver-filename-and-version-using-powershell.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To get hardware information, you need to create an object of `ManagementObjectSearcher` class.

Following link might be helpful to you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24756/How-to-query-miniport-driver-information-802-11-OI

Following link has all the code:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/217155/get-a-list-of-installed-drivers

Comment: I have achieved the same information using WMI query for Win32_NetworkAdapter. But this doesn't give me the list of driver file which is shown in right part of the image. Neither the link you have given is able to do so.

Comment: ohh, thike , mi search karato , kahi upayogi yenarr aasel tar link/code share karin.

Comment: hi link paha barr http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/217155/get-a-list-of-installed-drivers

Comment: I have already browsed all the links you have provided. Actually all those points to WMI query for either Win32_NetworkAdapter or Win32_SystemDriver